# Click to scroll to element horizontally

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create horizontal scrolling DIVs when a button is pressed it will scroll to the corresponding DIV ID.

I have used the following code but it is acting quite buggy, for example if you click to section 2 then click 3 whilst on section 2.

I need for the sections to be 200px off the left, rather than scroll to 0px at the left. I think this has caused me to run into issues.

Here is the fiddle to see it in action

http://jsfiddle.net/susannalarsen/vurbwete/

```
    .nav {
        position:absolute;
        z-index:10000;
        background:red;
        left:0;
    }
    #content {
    position:absolute;
    left:200px;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    overflow:auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    background:green;
}
.inner-content {
height:105%;
padding-right:9000px;   
}
#control-faders-wrapper {
white-space:nowrap;
padding-right:200000px;
}
.section{
margin:0px;
bottom:0px;
width:600px;
display:inline-block;
height:100%;
text-shadow:1px 1px 2px #f0f0f0;
}
.black{
color:#fff;

background:#000 url(../images/black.jpg) no-repeat top right;
}
.white{
color:#000;
background:#fff url(../images/white.jpg) no-repeat top right;
}

.desk-fader-container {
background:#e8e8e8;
border:1px solid #d2d2d2;
padding:7px;
font-size:12px;
text-align:center;
display:inline-block;
margin-left:10px;
padding-top:20px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 7px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 7px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
white-space:normal;
width:100px;
}
```

HTML :

```
                    <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="#section1">1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section2">2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section3">3</a></li>
               </ul>

    <div id="content">
    <div class="inner-content">
    <div id="control-faders-wrapper">
        <div class="desk-fader-container black" id="section1">
            <h2>Section 1</h2>
            <p>
                MY Spectre around me night and day
                Like a wild beast guards my way;
                My Emanation far within
                Weeps incessantly for my sin.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="desk-fader-container">
            <p>
                ‘A fathomless and boundless deep,
                There we wander, there we weep;
                On the hungry craving wind
                My Spectre follows thee behind.

            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="desk-fader-container">
            <p>
                ‘He scents thy footsteps in the snow
                Wheresoever thou dost go,
                Thro’ the wintry hail and rain.
                When wilt thou return again?

            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="desk-fader-container">
            <p>
                ‘He scents thy footsteps in the snow
                Wheresoever thou dost go,
                Thro’ the wintry hail and rain.
                When wilt thou return again?

            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="desk-fader-container">
            <p>
                ‘He scents thy footsteps in the snow
                Wheresoever thou dost go,
                Thro’ the wintry hail and rain.
                When wilt thou return again?

            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="desk-fader-container">
            <p>
                ‘He scents thy footsteps in the snow
                Wheresoever thou dost go,
                Thro’ the wintry hail and rain.
                When wilt thou return again?

            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="desk-fader-container">
            <p>
                ‘He scents thy footsteps in the snow
                Wheresoever thou dost go,
                Thro’ the wintry hail and rain.
                When wilt thou return again?

            </p>
        </div>

        <div class="desk-fader-container black" id="section2">
            <h2>Section 2</h2>
            <p>
                MY Spectre around me night and day
                Like a wild beast guards my way;
                My Emanation far within
                Weeps incessantly for my sin.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="desk-fader-container">
            <p>
                ‘A fathomless and boundless deep,
                There we wander, there we weep;
                On the hungry craving wind
                My Spectre follows thee behind.

            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="desk-fader-container">
            <p>
                ‘He scents thy footsteps in the snow
                Wheresoever thou dost go,
                Thro’ the wintry hail and rain.
                When wilt thou return again?

            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="desk-fader-container">
            <p>
                ‘He scents thy footsteps in the snow
                Wheresoever thou dost go,
                Thro’ the wintry hail and rain.
                When wilt thou return again?

            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="desk-fader-container">
            <p>
                ‘He scents thy footsteps in the snow
                Wheresoever thou dost go,
                Thro’ the wintry hail and rain.
                When wilt thou return again?

            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="desk-fader-container">
            <p>
                ‘He scents thy footsteps in the snow
                Wheresoever thou dost go,
                Thro’ the wintry hail and rain.
                When wilt thou return again?

            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="desk-fader-container">
            <p>
                ‘He scents thy footsteps in the snow
                Wheresoever thou dost go,
                Thro’ the wintry hail and rain.
                When wilt thou return again?

            </p>
        </div>


        <div class="desk-fader-container black" id="section3">
            <h2>Section 3</h2>
            <p>
                MY Spectre around me night and day
                Like a wild beast guards my way;
                My Emanation far within
                Weeps incessantly for my sin.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="desk-fader-container">
            <p>
                ‘A fathomless and boundless deep,
                There we wander, there we weep;
                On the hungry craving wind
                My Spectre follows thee behind.

            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="desk-fader-container">
            <p>
                ‘He scents thy footsteps in the snow
                Wheresoever thou dost go,
                Thro’ the wintry hail and rain.
                When wilt thou return again?

            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="desk-fader-container">
            <p>
                ‘He scents thy footsteps in the snow
                Wheresoever thou dost go,
                Thro’ the wintry hail and rain.
                When wilt thou return again?

            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="desk-fader-container">
            <p>
                ‘He scents thy footsteps in the snow
                Wheresoever thou dost go,
                Thro’ the wintry hail and rain.
                When wilt thou return again?

            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="desk-fader-container">
            <p>
                ‘He scents thy footsteps in the snow
                Wheresoever thou dost go,
                Thro’ the wintry hail and rain.
                When wilt thou return again?

            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="desk-fader-container">
            <p>
                ‘He scents thy footsteps in the snow
                Wheresoever thou dost go,
                Thro’ the wintry hail and rain.
                When wilt thou return again?

            </p>
        </div>


    </div>
    </div><!--inner-content-->
    </div><!--end of content
```

SCRIPT:

```
$(function() {
                $('.nav a').bind('click',function(event){
                    var $anchor = $(this);
                    /*
                    if you want to use one of the easing effects:
                    $('html, body').stop().animate({
                        scrollLeft: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().left
                    }, 1500,'easeInOutExpo');
                     */
                    $('#content').stop().animate({
                        scrollLeft: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().left - 200
                    }, 1000);
                    event.preventDefault();
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you scroll the content, the offset position actually changes as the elements move so you never get the right position.

The solution is to either calculate the correct position using the amount it's already scrolled, or just store the initial offset, which seems a lot easier

```
$(function () {
    $('.nav a').each(function() {
        $(this).data('left', $($(this).attr('href')).offset().left);
    }).on('click', function (event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('#content').stop().animate({
            scrollLeft: $anchor.data('left') - 200
        }, 1000);
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/vurbwete/1/)

Comment: This is perfect! I could tell it was doing something with the offset position but I couldn't just work out how to set it. Storing the initial offset seems to work great. I'm glad I can end the day with this working now finally! Thankyou

Comment: By any chance do you know how to change the value "200" to say "150" depending on the window screensize?

Would it be something like putting it in an if statement like "if($(window).width() <= 900)" or is there maybe a way of changing the "200" to a css class and changing the sizes with media queries?

Comment: that may be one for a separate question..Im not sure

Comment: @SuziLarsen - Something like this I think -> **http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/vurbwete/2/**

Comment: Brilliant! That is so much better than what I was thinking of. Thankyou.